# Fastest way to fill DataTable manually in C#

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I want to know if someone of you know a faster way to fill a DataTable manually then I do.

Here is what I got, I have a List with about 1.7b entries.
I want to fill this entries as fast as possible into DataTable with one column.
An entry in my list looks like this here `{"A2C","DDF","ER","SQ","8G"}`

My code need about 7-8 seconds

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lists.Count; i++)
{
    table_list.Rows.Add();
}

for (int a = 0; a < list.Count; a++)
{
    table_list.Rows[a][0] = list[a][0] + list[a][1] + 
        list[a][2] + list[a][3] + list[a][4];
}
```

As I didn't find any similar question on the board (just questions about how to fill datatable by sql and fill method), I decided to post my question.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: "Here is what I got, I have a List with about 1.7b entries. I want to fill this entries as fast as possible into DataTable with one column." - I have to ask: *why*? what is the thing you are going to do with this `DataTable`? because so far: that sounds like a terrible, terrible idea. Depending on what you want to do next: there may be much more efficient approaches here.

Comment: i add this DataTable into an sql server database (i do this by SqlBulkCopy)

Comment: k; I thought so: **don't do that**! will post an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i add this DataTable into an sql server database (i do this by SqlBulkCopy)

This is a mistake; the `DataTable` is pure overhead here. What you should expose is an `IDataReader` over that data. This API is a bit tricky, but [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember) makes it easier. For example, it sounds like you have 1 column; so consider:

```
class Foo {
    public string ColumnName {get;set;}
}
```

Now write an **iterator block** method that converts this from the original list per item:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> Convert(List<TheOldType> list) {
    foreach(var row in list) {
        yield return new Foo { ColumnName = /* TODO */ };
    }
}
```

and now create an `IDataReader` via FastMember on top of that lazy sequence:

```
List<TheOldType> list
var data = Convert(list);
using(var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data, "ColumnName"))
{
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable";
    bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
}
```

This works much better than populating a `DataTable` - in particular, it avoids populating a huge `DataTable`. Emphasis: the above is **spooling** - not buffered.

Comment: Well your solution gets me another second. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is gold! Thank you. We spend at least a few seconds in our code just populating the data table when the data is all already there, just in the wrong format.

Comment: Marc, I have implemeted a version of this (with a different EnumeratorDataReader) and I have 2 million records in the list, but only the LAST 500K get insert into Sql. Any idea why that might be? I set bactcsize to 0, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you create an empty row first, then loop the table again to fill them?

I would use a simple `foreach`:

```
var table_list = new DataTable();
table_list.Columns.Add();
foreach(string[] fields in lists)
{
    DataRow newRow = table_list.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField(0, string.Join("", fields));
}
```

Why do you put all into one field?

Comment: I get an IndexOutOfRangeException with the message: colum 0 not found. As i cant simple add a colum like i did before, i cant fix the problem

Comment: @user3868224: how have you initialized the `DataTable`? Of course you need to add a column. I've edited my answer to show you how.

Comment: Well i forgot to do that ;) your code need 6.2 seconds is there anyway i can get even more speed here?

Comment: @user3868224: i wonder why you care about one or two seconds if you want to fill a table in memory with 1.7 billion rows, then fill a database table via `SqlBulkCopy` which again will take  some time. Nobody expects it to be faster. If someone waits until all are inserted you should consider to do that in background and inform the user when you're finished. On that way the user can do something else meanwhile. How often do you need to insert so many rows? This is worth reading: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the `LoadDataRow` method of the `DataTable`.

```
// turnoff notifications
table_list.BeginLoadData();

// load each row into the table
foreach(string[] fields in lists)
    table_list.LoadDataRow(new object[] { string.Join("", fields) }, false);

// turn notifications back on
table_list.EndLoadData();
```

Also see: *DataTable.LoadDataRow Method* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcy03ww2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: your code also need 6.2 seconds, do you know anyway faster way?

Comment: I don't know any faster way, maybee directly add it -> `foreach(string[] fields in lists)
    table_list.Rows.Add(new object[] { string.Join("", fields) }, false);` But won't give much difference I guess. I think the fastest way is not using a DataTable. Can you explain why you want it into a `DataTable`?

Comment: i need to add as fast as possible my data into a sql server. i do this by sqlbulkcopy and this DataTable

Comment: using the `.WriteToServer(DataTable)` method? What uses the most time, when importing? Are you measuring the time to convert to a `DataTable`?

Comment: I think creating your own `IDataReader` implementation will do the trick. The problem is, that you load the data twice. From source to a `DataTable` and from `DataTable` to the Bulkcopy. If you directly give the source data via your own `IDataReader` to the Bulkcopy, you will improve performance.. **(using the WriteToServer(IDataReader) method)**

Comment: the most time is used to create the DataTable (with new code 6.2sec) to send the DataTable with sqlbulkcopy just take 2.8 sec

Comment: i will test it with own IDataReader and give a feedback tomorrow, thank you

Comment: @user3868224 you can perhaps avoid some work there - `FastMember` exposes an `IEnumerable<T>` as an `IDataReader`

Comment: LoadDataRow calls NewRow and AddRow in the simple case: it also has logic for other cases, including editing. On the other hand, Rows.Add calls NewRow and AddRow _without_ any other checks. tldr: it's a different use-case, and slightly (for some meaningless value) 'less efficient' to use LoadData row instead of Rows.Add on a for-transfer-only DataTable.